# grouping a table with different dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below,

```
SalesId   ItemId     DateSale       USDVal
ABC       01A        2018-04-01     52
ABC       01B        2018-04-01     300
ABC       01C        2018-04-01     12
ABC       01D        2018-04-01     62
ABC       01A        2018-03-23     66
MNB       01A        2018-01-01     584
MNB       01A        2018-02-20     320
MNB       01F        2018-02-20     5
```

I want to write a query that selects the last date for each SalesId and shows those records so the result would look something like below.

**Result**

```
SalesId   ItemId     DateSale       USDVal
ABC       01A        2018-04-01     52
ABC       01B        2018-04-01     300
ABC       01C        2018-04-01     12
ABC       01D        2018-04-01     62
MNB       01A        2018-02-20     320
MNB       01F        2018-02-20     5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, the fastest way is often a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.datesale = (select max(t2.datesale) from t t2 where t2.salesid = t.salesid);
```

Comment: The only issue I see is if there are two transactions with the same SalesID on the same date. Not sure if that is really possible, but the sample data suggests it is.